# Posts relacionados por categorias filho

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu tenho o seguinte código funcionando, que mostra os posts relacionados no wordpress, pela categoria (mãe).

Preciso adaptar esse código para que em um determinado tipo de post, ele mostre os posts relacionados pela categoria filho. Por exemplo

Minha estrutura de categorias está como:

- Categoria Mãe

  - Categoria Filho1
  - Categoria Filho2
  - Categoria Filho3

Se o post tiver a "Categoria Mãe" e "Categoria Filho2", irá aparecer posts relacionados de toda "Categoria Mãe".

O ideal para o site, é que apareça somente da "Categoria Filho2". E se o post for "Categoria Mãe" e "Categoria Filho1", aparecer somente "Categoria Filho1" e etc.

Abaixo segue o código que gera os meus related posts.

```
<?php 
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);  
if ($categories) {  $category_ids = array();  
  foreach($categories as $individual_category)  
    $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id; 

  $args=array( 
    'category__in' => $category_ids, 
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), 
    'showposts'=>4,
    'caller_get_posts'=>1 
  ); 
  $my_query = new wp_query($args); 

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
    echo '<h3 class="related__title title--article-footer">Artigos relacionados:</h3><div class="row">';
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) { 
      $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>">
        <h2 class="related__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <h3 class="related__subtitle"><?php the_excerpt() ?></h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <?php } 
    echo '</div>'; 
    wp_reset_query();
  } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu entendi duas coisas diferentes da pergunta, então segue duas respostas:

Se o que você precisa é ter uma categoria específica que quando estiver presente os posts relacionados serão somente dela, use isso:

```
$filha_unica = 20; // o term_id da categoria que você não quer que traga posts da categoria mãe

foreach($categories as $individual_category) {

    // O de sempre aqui, pega o id da categoria para relacionar
    $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

    // Se apareceu o id da categoria $filha_unica, use apenas ele
    if( $individual_category->term_id === $filha_unica ) {
        $category_ids = array( $filha_unica );
        break;
    }
}
```

Se o que você precisa é que sempre que uma categoria filha estiver presente, não usar os ids das categorias mães, use isso:

```
foreach($categories as $individual_category) {

    // Guarde filhas e mães em arrays separados
    if( $individual_category->category_parent > 0 ) {
        $cat_filhas[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    } else {
        $cat_maes[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    }
}


// Se não houver categorias filhas, use as mães e vice versa
if ( empty( $cat_filhas ) ) {
    $category_ids = $cat_maes;
} else {
    $category_ids = $cat_filhas;
}
```

Comment: Troco "foreach($categories as $individual_category)" por "foreach($categories as $individual_category) {

    // Guarde filhas e mães em arrays separados
    if( $individual_category->category_parent > 0 ) {
        $cat_filhas[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    } else {
        $cat_maes[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    }
}" ?